# What's the correct PEP8 practice for this long Python line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pep8

How should I break down this line so it abides by PEP8?

```
    assert (sum(map(lambda x: len(x), 
                    (activities,apps,classes,users,verbs))) ==
            Object.query
                  .filter(Object.status != ObjectStatusChoices.DELETED)
                  .count())
```

Comment: Well, first off you should replace `lambda x: len(x)` by just `len`. :)

Comment: What wasn't clear in [PEP-8's maximum line length section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)?

Comment: Really, I think most people would say that it's far more pythonic to break this into multiple lines, and name the intermediate values (or even refactor pieces into functions and name _them_), at which point the original question becomes moot.

Comment: @Lattyware: Unless you consider `.` an operator, it doesn't explain how to line up the last three lines. (I think the reason for that is that you should rarely be writing something like those last three lines—and, if you must, you can usually indent the args instead of the methods.)

Comment: @abarnert PEP-8 is pretty clear that you shouldn't split on `.` like that, instead, split on arguments or split into multiple lines with more variables.

Comment: @Dougal each element of the tuple is a list; therefore, I use lambda x: len(x) instead of rewriting len(x) for each element of the tuple.

Comment: @DogukanTufekci His point is that you make a function that calls `len(x)` given `x`, but there is already a function that does that, `len`. `lambda x: len(x)` is the same as `len` except with a wrapper. You are forgetting that in Python, all functions are first order objects, lamdas are just a quick way to write small functions.

Comment: @Lattyware: I don't think it _is_ clear—I think it's so obvious to anyone who gets the philosophy behind PEP8 that it never gets stated. (Also, how _do_ you break up `PyObjC` stuff like `Foundation.NSRidiculouslyLongClassNameBecauseILoveSteveJobs.NSEvenLongerNameForASymbolicConstantThatGoesOnForever`?)

Comment: @Lattyware please help me understand if you are referring to a different solution than stated below:
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ['a','b','c']
c = ['1','2','3']

sum(map(lambda x: len(x), (a,b,c)))

Comment: @abarnert You do `ilsj = Foundation.NSRidiculouslyLongClassNameBecauseILoveSteveJobs` and go from there.

Comment: @DogukanTufekci `lambda x: len(x)` is a function object that takes one argument (we will call `x`) and returns `len(x)`. `len` is a function object that takes one argument (we will call `x`) and returns `len(x)`. Try doing both `sum(map(lambda x: len(x), (a,b,c)))` and `sum(map(len, (a,b,c)))` - they are the same.

Comment: Please review my previous comment as I edited ...

Comment: It's `map()` that's applying the function to each element, `lambda` is just a way to make a function. Try both the examples in my comment and see.

Comment: @Lattyware Okay I get it know. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

If you rewrite things into separate lines, this never comes up.

It also lets you give meaningful names to the intermediate values (which I had to guess at, but presumably you know them), or even refactor bits of logic out into functions (which you can *also* give meaningful names to).

For example, not changing any of your logic, or even rewriting any of it (except to use `len` in place of `lambda x: len(x)`):

```
lengths = map(len, (activities,apps,classes,users,verbs))
db_query = Object.query.filter(Object.status != ObjectStatusChoices.DELETED)
assert sum(lengths) == db_query.count()
```

Comment: One minor problem with this approach is that if you run with `python -O`, which removes asserts, this will still create the `lengths` and `db_query` lists and then just ignore them (in this case, it presumably won't hit the database, but still unnecessary). Not that anyone should really be using `python -O`, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @Dougal: Good point. Of course the solution to that is obvious: move the whole check into a function, and `assert check_lengths()` (which also means you can make this a postcondition or invariant that gets reused, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keep in mind that there is no single "correct PEP8 answer" to this.  I prefer:

```
in_mem = sum(len(x) for x in (activities,apps,classes,users,verbs))
in_db = Object.query.filter(
                        Object.status != ObjectStatusChoices.DELETED
                        ).count()
assert in_mem == in_db
```

Definitely if you find yourself with a statement that needs to be split onto five lines, you probably want more statements.

Comment: PEP-8 would recommend indenting line 4 to either match the bracket or by only one block, and moving line 5 to the end of line 4.

Comment: While that may be, the question does explicitly ask for PEP-8, and most other programmers will expect to follow it. The whole point of PEP-8 is to make a consistent standard, as people will always have different preference. It's about being courteous to others by being consistent.

Comment: Actually, on re-examining PEP8, I don't see any explicit recommendations that I am violating.  PEP-8 actually says fairly little about how to break long lines.

Comment: *Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and braces, or using a hanging indent. When using a hanging indent the following considerations should be applied; there should be no arguments on the first line and further indentation should be used to clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.* - you are indenting too far, there is no block below line 4 that means that line should have further indentation - see the examples in that section of PEP-8. One indent if the line has no block, two if it does.

Comment: @Lattyware: sorry, nothing in that italicized sentence precludes extra indentation.  PEP8 tools may complain, but there's no text in PEP8 that says what I have is wrong.  People seem to want PEP8 to tell them exactly how to format their code.  It doesn't try to do that.

Comment: I think when every example shows something done a given way, it's clear what the spirit of it was. I don't see how shoving random amounts of extra indentation makes this anything other than less readable? It's about consistency - it's nice to know where one should be looking for the next bit of code, and following the style given makes that easier.